# Unable to get docment details using Tuleap REST API in LabVIEW

Tags: labview, tuleap

I am using Tuleap 10.7 and LabVIEW 2017 sp1.  Using the HTTP communication in LabVIEW, I was able to authenticate and retrieve project informations but I could not retrieve any document information using the method "docman_items" as detailed https://tuleap.net/api/explorer/#/.

[docman_items description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKrog.png)

I tried to either query the trackers or the project first(they worked fine), and then verify the ID of the document/file that I wanted to retrieve.  The error returned is always "404 Not Found ".

The project in question is a public project of which I am a member.

The problem I think is not with LabVIEW but the function docman_items in general. Has anyone tried this function?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so the answer might be the docman function is integrated in the version Tuleap 10.7.99.45.... so it will be available in Tuleap 10.8. That is why we can't use it in Tuleap 10.7